# lightdm and startx fail to start graphics mode; traces of Nvidia driver are involved

Tags: nvidia, xorg, lightdm

My Ubuntu 12.04 system boots to a text mode login prompt (virtual console #1) since I upgraded the kernel (using Ubuntu's automatic upgrade system). I was using an Nvidia driver that worked well until that update. I had installed it from Nvidia's shell script instead of apt-get.

I have uninstalled this driver. I also tried Ubuntu's nvidia-current package, without success. I have purged it. I also reinstalled the desktop packages using "apt-get install ubuntu-desktop".

Rebooting still boots to text mode. Doing "sudo service lightdm restart" does not go to graphics mode. It just switches to virtual console #7.

As a test, I run `sudo startx` from a text mode shell, and it fails with this message:

```
FATAL: Error inserting nvidia_304 (/lib/modules/3.8.0-34-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia_304.ko): No such device
```

That .ko file exists and contains 15254672 bytes.

It seems like the system still wants to use the Nvidia driver, even though I uninstalled it.

How can I tell startx to avoid the Nvidia driver completely? Once startx would work, I assume lightdm might work too. Then I could try to reinstall the Nvidia driver.

I have looked at numerous pages on this forum, but everybody seems to have a different variant of this problem.

`uname -a` reports `3.8.0-34-generic`. The PC is an x86_64. The system has the `linux-headers-3.8.0-34-generic` package, according to `dpkg -l`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using 12.04, it may be possible to use the command-line version of the 'Additional Drivers' tool, called `jockey-text`. To get started, log in at one of the virtual terminals (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F*n*</kbd> where *n* is 1,2,..6) and then type

```
jockey-text --list 2>/dev/null
```

(the `2>/dev/null` is optional - it just hides a bunch of error messages about other hardware / drivers). It will take some time since it searches online but you should eventually see a list like

```
xorg:nvidia_173 - NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in use)
xorg:nvidia_173_updates - NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (post-release updates) (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in use)
xorg:nvidia_304 - NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in use)
xorg:nvidia_304_updates - NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (post-release updates) (Proprietary, Enabled, In use)
xorg:nvidia_319 - NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in use)
xorg:nvidia_319_updates - NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (post-release updates) (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in use)
```

From here you can proceed in one of two ways (both equivalent, as far as I know):

1. disable the current (troublesome) driver, so that the system falls back to the previous - hopefully good - driver e.g. if `xorg:nvidia_304_updates` is currently `Enabled, In use` then do

   ```
   sudo jockey-text --disable xorg:nvidia_304_updates
   ```
2. explicitly enable a previous known good driver e.g.

   ```
   sudo jockey-text --enable xorg:nvidia_304
   ```

If you get a message about being unable to connect to the system bus, then try adding the `--no-dbus` switch e.g. `sudo jockey-text --no-dbus --disable xorg:nvidia_304_updates`

Comment: I saw 3 drivers, one was Enabled, so I disabled it, then "sudo startx" worked.

When I reboot, I get the graphical login, but when I log in, I get an empty text mode screen, then I'm immediately returned to the login screen.

I was using XFCE before this began. Maybe my previous configuration is interfering with something. Logging in with "Guest Session" logs me in successfully in a GNOME 3 desktop.

Is there something I could delete in my home directory to reset my desktop configuration? Or should I look elsewhere for the cause? Thanks again.

Comment: Doing "sudo rm .Xauthority" in my home directory resolved this last issue.

Comment: Yes I was about to suggest that - for the record, that's caused by using sudo with startx (it causes the user's .Xauthority to become owned by root) - always run startx as a regular user. BTW if the issue is solved please consider marking the answer as 'Accepted' - that makes it easier for others with the same problem to find a solution.

Comment: Update: The above procedure restored 1024x768 graphics. I was only able to get 1280x1024 again by installing NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.38.run myself, not by using Ubuntu's NVidia driver package (which failed to offer more than 1024). My graphics card is a GeForce GT 630 Rev. 2 on a 64-bit PC purchased in Fall 2013.